# Compilation to the web

Tags: web, compilation, webassembly

What format does WebAssembly compile code to?

From official site:

```
WebAssembly or wasm is a new portable, size- and load-time-efficient format 
suitable for compilation to the web.
```

Answer (score 4):

WebAssembly is compiled to, and typically distributed in, a binary format.

For example, here is a simple C function:

```
int increment(int input) {
  return ++input;
}
```

Which compiles to the following:

```
00000000: 0061 736d 0100 0000 0106 0160 017f 017f  .asm.......`....
00000010: 0302 0100 0404 0170 0000 0503 0100 0107  .......p........
00000020: 1602 066d 656d 6f72 7902 0009 696e 6372  ...memory...incr
00000030: 656d 656e 7400 000a 0901 0700 2000 4101  ement....... .A.
00000040: 6a0b
```

You can find a specification for this binary encoding in the [WebAssembly design documents](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/BinaryEncoding.md).

However, if you want to see the compiled output, you can use the `wasm2wast` tool to convert it into a more readable text format (S-expression). Here is the same code:

```
(module
 (table 0 anyfunc)
 (memory $0 1)
 (export "memory" (memory $0))
 (export "increment" (func $increment))
 (func $increment (param $0 i32) (result i32)
  (i32.add
   (get_local $0)
   (i32.const 1)
  )
 )
)
```

Comment: Great answer! i suggest adding a link to the binary encoding documentation: https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/BinaryEncoding.md

Comment: Thanks @JFBastien - I've added the link. Just started learning about WebAssembly myself. It feels like quite a mountain to climb at the moment!